# How to parameterise multiple tuples using psycopg2, without using an f-string

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm wondering how I would parameterise the following postgres:

```sql
UPDATE your_table as t
SET val = x.val_to
FROM ( VALUES 
  (1, 20),
  (3, 44)
) as x (val_from, val_to)
WHERE t.val = x.val_from
AND
your_table.other_id = %(other_id_value)
;
```

where `(1, 20), (3, 44)` would be parameterised using psycopg2.

Using :

```py
cur.execute("""
UPDATE your_table as t
SET val = x.val_to
FROM ( VALUES 
  $(vals)s
) as x (val_from, val_to)
WHERE t.val = x.val_from
AND
your_table.other_id = %(other_id_value)s
;
""", { 
    'other_id_value' : 3843,
    'vals' : [(1, 20), (3, 44)] 
}
)
```

Doesn't work.

In psycopg2 https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html they have:

```py
>>> execute_values(cur,
... """UPDATE test SET v1 = data.v1 FROM (VALUES %s) AS data (id, v1)
... WHERE test.id = data.id""",
... [(1, 20), (4, 50)])
```

But I need to parameterise the `data.id` there as well, not just the `VALUES`.

Comment: Look at psycopg2's `execute_batch()`.  Since a common use case for me is moving JSON-RPC results into PostgreSQL, I use the `jsonb` functions on passed json, instead.  Please comment if you are interested in seeing how I would do that.

Comment: @MikeOrganek that would be interesting to see if it solves the problem outlined in this question, thanks

Answer (score 2):

[psycopg2.extras](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html) provides the function psycopg2.extras.execute_values just for this purpose.

Given the need to include another parameter, I would just decorate the tuples with an extra member which is constant over all the tuples, so you then would have an alias like `AS data (id, v1, c1)`.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes - I wasn't aware of that. I've updated the post though with an additional parameter - the `WHERE` requires a parameterised filter which I initially thought wasn't relevant to the question, but I think with `extras.execute_values` it is. I updated the post with information from the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve this with @jjanes `execute_batch()`.

The json approach I mentioned in my comments is:

```
with invars as (
  select (j->>0)::int as val_from, (j->>1)::int as val_to, %s as other_id
    from jsonb_array_elements((%s)::jsonb) as e(j)
)
update your_table as t
   set val = i.val_to
  from invars i
 where t.val = i.val_from
   and t.other_id = i.other_id
```

The python execute would look like:

```
cur.execute(<above sql>, (other_id, json.dumps([(1, 20), (3, 44)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module. Not tested on actual data.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values


other_id_value = 3843
vals = [(1, 20), (3, 44)] 

qry_sql = sql.SQL("""UPDATE your_table as t
SET val = x.val_to
FROM ( VALUES %) as x (val_from, val_to)
WHERE t.val = x.val_from
AND
your_table.other_id = {}""").format(sql.Literal(other_id_value))

cur.execute(qry_sql, vals)
```